# How do you register two or more keys properly?

Tags: java, game-mechanics, keyboard

I am experimenting with `KeyListeners` and I thought about how do I register two or more keys, this is my code so far:

```
package engine.listeners;

import engine.Frame;
import engine.KeyCodes;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Key extends KeyAdapter implements KeyCodes, ActionListener {

    private static HashSet<Integer> keyMap = new HashSet<>();
    private Timer tm;

    public Key() {
        tm = new Timer(0, this);
        tm.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (!keyMap.contains(e.getKeyCode())) keyMap.add(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keyMap.remove(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int x = Frame.moveMe.getX();
        int y = Frame.moveMe.getY();
        if (keyMap.contains(arrowLeft)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(--x, y);
        if (keyMap.contains(arrowUp)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(x, --y);
        if (keyMap.contains(arrowRight)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(++x, y);
        if (keyMap.contains(arrowDown)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(x, ++y);
    }
}
```

Right here, it's doing 2 registered keys properly, for example `arrow left` and `arrow top` goes diagonal left top.
But one thing I noticed, sometimes when I registered 3 or more keys, it's not working properly for example: `arrow left`, `arrow right`, and `arrow up` should just go up, but what happened is it ignored the key 'right', and so it continues going diagonal top left.

Is there a way to improve this? or should I implement another type of listener that is not buggy as `KeyListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small issue with the logic in the `actionPefromed` function: you use "stale" data. You currently have this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int x = Frame.moveMe.getX();
    int y = Frame.moveMe.getY();
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowLeft)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(--x, y);
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowUp)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(x, --y);
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowRight)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(++x, y);
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowDown)) Frame.moveMe.setXY(x, ++y);
}
```

What you need is this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int x = Frame.moveMe.getX();
    int y = Frame.moveMe.getY();
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowLeft)) --x;
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowUp)) --y;
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowRight)) ++x;
    if (keyMap.contains(arrowDown)) ++y;
    
    Frame.moveMe.setXY(x,y);
}
```

Essentially, you update the temporary values, then when you're done, you update the position with the updated temporary values.